# Given S-Parameters (or Y,Z,T,ABCD), how can you calculate \$Q_C\$ and \$Q_L\$ (or, how do you calculate ESR)?

Tags: rf, filter, reactance, s-parameters, esr

#### Background

I'm writing a [.s2p/Touchstone library for Perl](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::IO::Touchstone) and I'm trying to get the Q value of a component given an S-parameter matrix.

#### The Goal

In this case I'm trying to get Q for a [10nF muRata capacitor](https://www.murata.com/products/productdetail.aspx?partno=GRM1555CYA103GE01%23).  I'm checking correctness against the Q graph in their [SimSurfing app](https://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing/mlcc.html?lcid=en-us&jis=false&md5=044e76c970e0dd6a84ddb6741cc4e6b7) and so far the result isn't lining up to what they provide.

#### What I've tried

Given that \$ Q_C = \frac{X_C}{ESR} \$, I have already validated that \$X_C\$ is correct (by comparing to muRata's graphs) but I've not found a way to calculate [ESR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance) to find \$Q_C\$. [Somewhere I read](https://mdpi-res.com/d_attachment/electronics/electronics-11-02029/article_deploy/electronics-11-02029.pdf) that \$ESR=\frac{-1}{Re(Y_{12})}\$ but the values aren't coming out right, so maybe that is true only under certain conditions? (I know that \$Y_{12}\$ is correct because the capacitance value using \$Y_{12}\$ is close to 10nF.)

[This reference](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/2/2866.html) provides quite a few from S-parameter conversions, but not ESR.  I've read articles about [how it relates to `tan(dissipation)`](https://www.ieee.li/pdf/essay/s_parameters_of_passive_components.pdf) and [how to measure ESR](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/MethodsandProblemsmeasuringESR.pdf)...but nothing on how to get ESR from S-parameters.

#### The questions

I can convert S-parameters to Y, Z, ABCD, T, or whatever...so if those are better for this purpose then I'm fine with that too.

1. So this question is fundamentally:

   - **How do you calculate Q from S-parameters?**
2. However as an [xyproblem](https://xyproblem.info/), an answer to this question would also suffice because it provides #1:

   - **How do you calculate ESR from S-parameters?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my math for ESR was wrong.

1. Above I have this which is **incorrect**, at least for Y-parameters that have complex values:

   - \$ESR=\frac{-1}{Re(Y_{12})}\$
2. The **correct** form to calculate ESR is:

   - \$ESR=Re(\frac{-1}{Y_{12}})\$

Subtle difference!  Now my numbers match muRata's.

Comment: Shows the 'Teddy Bear Effect' is alive and well!